# How to pass schema name in a variable to nHibernate's named query?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a named native sql query in one of my nhibernate mapping files as follows:

```
<sql-query name="GetAllClients">
    <return alias="clientList" class="IBeam.Core.Models.Client"/>
    <![CDATA[
      SELECT a.sname Name, a.scd Id
        FROM :MASTER_USER.smast      a,
        :MASTER_USER.fa_ledmast b,
        :TRAN_USER.fa_subledmast c
      WHERE a.scd = c.subledcd
        AND b.ledgercd = c.ledgercd
        AND b.ledtypecd = 'SDR'
        AND a.catflg  = 'N'
     group by a.scd, a.sname
     order by a.sname
   ]]>
</sql-query>
```

And I am running this query as from my c# code as follows:

```
var query = Repository.GetExecutingSession().GetNamedQuery("GetAllClients").SetString("MASTER_USER", "test$master").SetString("TRAN_USER", "test$tran");
var clients = query.List<Models.Client>();
```

But I get the error: 
    Parameter MASTER_USER does not exist as a named parameter in the query.
I have used named queries and passed parameters to it before, but never as a schema name. I think it is considering the whole `:MASTER_USER.smast` as a table name and is not distinguishing the parameter name. How can I pass the schema name to this query as a parameter?

I found this [Link](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2576) so I think it can be done. But I don't know how to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your schema specifications can't be SQL parameters. The replacement would need to be performed by the NH engine, not by the SQL Engine. So your schema specifications would need to be in NH placeholders ( with angle brackets )

Then, the Hibernate Link you provided does not allow to pass schema as parameter. It allows to extract default schema from config.

Maybe (not tried) you can try something like this, with a (very rough) interceptor implementation :

```
public class SchemaSqlInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor, IInterceptor
{

    public string MASTER_USER { get; set; }
    public string TRAN_USER { get; set; }


    NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlString IInterceptor.OnPrepareStatement(NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlString sql)
    {
        return sql.Replace("{MASTER_USER}", MASTER_USER).Replace("{TRAN_USER}", TRAN_USER);
    }
}
```

Then :

```
    var interceptor = new SchemaSqlInterceptor();
    using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession(interceptor))
    {
        interceptor.MASTER_USER = "test$master";
        interceptor.TRAN_USER = "test$tran";
        var query = session.GetNamedQuery("GetAllClients");
        var clients = query.List<Models.Client>();
        session.Close();
    }
```

your query being :

```
<sql-query name="GetAllClients">
    <return alias="clientList" class="IBeam.Core.Models.Client"/>
    <![CDATA[
      SELECT a.sname Name, a.scd Id
        FROM {MASTER_USER}.smast      a,
        {MASTER_USER}.fa_ledmast b,
        {TRAN_USER}.fa_subledmast c
      WHERE a.scd = c.subledcd
        AND b.ledgercd = c.ledgercd
        AND b.ledtypecd = 'SDR'
        AND a.catflg  = 'N'
     group by a.scd, a.sname
     order by a.sname
   ]]>
</sql-query>
```

Comment: Thanks jbl. I am doing something similar to this right now. I had no idea about the Interceptor interface. What I was doing was after getting the query using `GetNamedQuery` I was manually creating another `IQuery` with the schema names manually replaced. Your implementation would keep this replacing logic in one place. I will try this now.

Comment: thx. Glad it helped. Keep in mind that this is rough implementation (no handling of conflicts between the schema placeholder and an entity with the same name, no handling of the dot when no schema value is provided in the interceptor)

Comment: yup. I was looking to modify this implementation a bit so that the interception occurs only when the query is a named query - one defined in the hbm file, and not the ones that are generated by NHibernate. Any inputs?

Comment: I must say I don't know how to track that in the interceptor. I was just thinking about a naming convention fot your placeholders, preventing it from being mixed-up with entity names.